# I wrote this code in Verilog and there are no error messages, but it doesn't work

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl, modelsim, quartus

This is the module:

```
module test (output reg [7:0] Q_out, input [2:0] data_in); 
always 
    begin
        case (data_in)
        3'b000: Q_out = 8'b10000000;
        3'b001: Q_out = 8'b01000000;
        3'b010: Q_out = 8'b00100000;
        3'b011: Q_out = 8'b00010000;
        3'b100: Q_out = 8'b00001000;
        3'b101: Q_out = 8'b00000100;
        3'b110: Q_out = 8'b00000010;
        3'b111: Q_out = 8'b00000001;
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

and this is the testbench

```
module test2();

reg [2:0]data_in;
wire [7:0] Q_out;

test uut (.data_in(data_in), .Q_out(Q_out));

initial begin

data_in=000;
#5;

data_in=001;
#5;

data_in=010;
#5;

data_in=011;
#5;

data_in=100;
#5;

data_in=101;
#5;

data_in=110;
#5;

data_in=111;
#5;
end

endmodule
```

Everything seems to work until I get to the simulation part.

[image: waves]

Then, after I try to simulate it, nothing really shows up in waveforms. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in the `test` module.
Change:

```
always
```

to:

```
always @*
```

Since there is no delay in your `always` block, it keeps triggering at time 0, and time does not advance in the simulation.  By adding a sensitivity list (`@*`), the block only triggers when any of it inputs (`data_in`) changes state.

You could also use `always_comb`.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 9.2.2.2.2 *always_comb compared to always @**